# Save a string to file on server via ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html + javascript page, which I'm using to collect data through "clicks" of the user (the user marks points in a given image). I have a few arrays which are being created the way I need, and I'm trying to get those arrays written to a server-side csv file (on a button click) using `ajax` and `php`. I've looked this up in various places, and am clearly missing something from those examples, because the submit action isn't working at all.

Here's a step to convert the arrays to a single string for writing to csv:

```
var output = "#name,time,x,y\n";
for( i = 0; i < pointsX.length; i++ ) {
    output += user;
    output += ",";
    output += time[i];
    output += ",";
    output += pointsX[i];
    output += ",";
    output += pointsY[i];
    output += "\n"
}
// alert( output ); // for testing
```

(Note when uncommented, the `alert` line displays the string, and it looks right for the csv file format I want.)

Then there's the `ajax` call to send that string to a `php` file:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "submit.php",
  data: {output: output},
  dataType: "json"
});
```

And the `php` file itself:

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['output'];
$file = "test.csv";
file_put_contents( $file, $string );
?>
```

My understanding is that the string should be received by the php file (located on the server, alongside the `html` file), which should then take the string and print it to the file "test.csv" (which at this stage would sit in the same folder alongside the `html` and `php` files). That file just isn't appearing at all.

I've tried this a few different ways, including using the below `jQuery` call in place of the `ajax` one above:

```
$.post( "submit.asp", output );
```

I do prefer the syntax here, but the result has been the same.

I've also tried the php like so, again with no output:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('php://input');
$file = "test.csv";
file_put_contents( $file, $string );
?>
```

I'm very new to these languages, so I'm piecing together what I can from various sources, but I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: check directory permissions

Comment: @charlietfl you're a gem, that's it! I've switched to sending the file to a subfolder, the permissions seemed fairly generous to begin with (already `755`), but I just did `chmod` to `777` and it works. I tried `666` (should be read and write permission) but that doesn't seem to do it. Opening up executable permissions seems dangerous, so what should the permissions be?